# Trouble with submitting high score to Facebook from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, java-native-interface

When I attempt to post a high score to Facebook with the code below, I receive this error:

```
Invalid indirect reference 0x12341234 in decodeIndirectRef
```

The error happens when the request is executed.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("score", "123");

Request postScoreRequest = new Request(session, 
                                       "/me/scores", 
                                       params, 
                                       HttpMethod.POST, 
                                       new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.d("test", "error: " + error);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("test", "success");
                    }
                }
});
postScoreRequest.executeAsync();
```

The above Java code is called from C++ via JNI. I have many similar C++ to Java JNI methods that work fine. I tried running the above high score submission code when the user first logs in to Facebook (so no JNI involved) and I didn't see the crash.

Why does calling the above code via JNI cause the error?

Edit: I noticed this crash happens at the next JNI call from C++ to Java. It can be totally unrelated to high scores. If I comment `postScoreRequest.executeAsync()` then the crash goes away. I'm trying to figure out how that line is affecting the JNI.

Edit: explicitly creating and executing the request on the UI thread works. I still want to understand why this is the case.

Comment: which part of  your code returning data back to java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your C++ code runs on a different thread than the UI Thread (*Because it's a game -> probably OpenGL -> Gl renderer starts it own thread*): Your Java thread is also not on the UI thread and Facebook's `executeAsync` should be ran on the UI thread:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Request/#executeAsync%28%29

> executeAsync() Executes this request and returns the response. This should only be called from the UI thread.

P.S. To fix it, I would call [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))